# SQL Server 2022 and Python3.10 script error

Tags: python-3.x, sql-server

I need to receive lists of files from a folder.
I run the small script but receive the error :

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N 'Python', 
@script = N 'print(__import__("os").walk(r''E:\\Backups\\''))' ------------
STDOUT message(s) 
from 
  external script : < generator object _walk at 0x0000015CD304DE00 >
```

The folder E:\Backups\ contains files.
What is incorrect in the script?

Comment: nothing is wrong, it just prints the iterator, not every file

Comment: File "C:\ProgramData\SQL2022\Temp-PY\Appcontainer1\538E038E-40BB-4324-96FD-6704E037A750\sqlindb_0.py", line 33, in transform
    for path in os.scandir(dir_path):
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'F:\\\\SharedBackup\\\\'
-------my SQL Server runs under Admin but what user runs python? May be he has no permissions?

Comment: I think that  os.walk function returns a generator object that yields a tuple containing the directory path, subdirectories, and filenames at each iteration. You need to iterate over the filenames returned by os.walk

Comment: You can use `list()` to execute the generator and return the results in a list.

Comment: "my SQL Server runs under Admin" sounds like a bad idea. Just give the Launchpad service user the correct permissions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/concepts/extensibility-framework?view=sql-server-ver16#launchpad

Comment: It is possible to use simple T-SQL to get a list of files in a directory.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Is it really ?  how to? but without OLE, cmd because it does not work in SQL Server (Linux) and in AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `dm_os_enumerate_filesystem()` dmv.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

The dmv accepts two parameters:

- Directory
- Files wildcard

**SQL**

```
-- SQL Server 2017 onwards
SELECT file_or_directory_name
   , level, is_directory, creation_time, size_in_bytes
FROM sys.dm_os_enumerate_filesystem
(
   N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn'
   , N'*.*'
);
```

**Output**

| file_or_directory_name | level | is_directory | creation_time | size_in_bytes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| batchparser.dll | 0 | 0 | 2022-10-08 10:33:18.0000000 | 190408 |
| bcp.exe | 0 | 0 | 2022-10-08 10:33:36.0000000 | 141224 |
| Resources | 0 | 1 | 2021-11-30 23:33:46.1047932 | 0 |
| SQLCMD.EXE | 0 | 0 | 2023-05-26 17:18:40.0000000 | 276376 |
| xmlrw.dll | 0 | 0 | 2019-09-24 19:27:18.0000000 | 347752 |
| 1033 | 1 | 1 | 2021-11-30 23:33:46.1053619 | 0 |
| bcp.rll | 2 | 0 | 2022-10-08 10:33:16.0000000 | 30664 |
| license_SQLCMD.txt | 2 | 0 | 2022-10-08 10:31:00.0000000 | 18102 |
| SQLCMD.rll | 2 | 0 | 2022-10-08 10:33:18.0000000 | 42912 |

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment (@Siggemannen also mentioned the same thing), the message you are getting is that you're printing the output of the os.walk function which returns a generator object that yields a tuple containing each iteration's directory path, subdirectories, and filenames.

To get the absolute path of each file, you need to iterate over the os.path.join and before that iterate over the filenames returned by os.walk.
In each iteration, paths are appended to the files list.

```
-- Create a table variable to store the output
DECLARE @OutputTable TABLE (FilePath NVARCHAR(MAX));

-- Execute the external script
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script
  @language = N'Python',
  @script = N'
import os
import pandas as pd

# Store the files in a list
files = []
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(r"E:\\Backups\\"):
    for filename in filenames:
        files.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

# Return the list of files
OutputDataSet = pd.DataFrame(files, columns=["FilePath"])
',
  @input_data_1 = N'',
  @output_data_1_name = N'OutputDataSet',
  @params = N'';

-- Insert the result into the table variable
INSERT INTO @OutputTable
SELECT FilePath FROM OutputDataSet;

-- Select the result from the table variable
SELECT FilePath FROM @OutputTable;
```

Comment: I have ran it again and : (0 rows affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 25
Invalid object name 'OutputDataSet'.